# Collectd server not writing down received client data

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, rackspace-cloud, collectd

I have pretty strange problem with Collectd. I'm not new to Collectd, was using it for a long time on CentOS based boxes, but now we have Ubuntu TLS 12.04 boxes, and I have really strange issue.

So, using version 5.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 TLS. Two boxes residing on Rackspace (maybe important, but I'm not sure). Network plugin configured using two local IPs, without any firewall in between and without any security (just to try to set simple client server scenario).

On both servers collectd writes in configured folders as it should write, but on server machine it doesn't write data received from client.

Troubleshooted with tcpdump, and I can clearly see UDP traffic and collectd data, including hostname and plugin names from my client machine, received on server, but they are not flushed to appropriate folder (configured by collectd) ever. Also running everything as root user, to avoid troubleshooting permissions.

Anyone has any idea or similar experience with this? Or maybe some idea what could I do for troubleshooting this beside trying to crawl internet (I think I clicked on every sensible link Google gave me in last two days) and checking network layer (which looks fine)?

And just small note: exactly the same happened with official 4.10.2 version from Ubuntu's repo. After trying to troubleshoot it for hours moved to upgrade to version five.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying out the quite generic troubleshooting procedure based on the *csv* and *logfile* plugins, as described in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/499378/collectd-stores-nan-instead-of-correct-value-in-ubuntu-12-04) answer. As everything seems to be fine locally, follow this procedure on the server, activating only the *network* plugin (in addition to *logfile*, *csv* and possibly *rrdtool*).

Comment: In the meantime, I upgraded to 5.3 but still no luck. 

I saw this answer before, but in this case it's not helping. Problems are that collectd logs are in this case not helpful at all, this example (only with CSV) doesn't even create a folder, and I'm not able to catch any useful output anywhere for now... 

RRDTool is up to date, latest and greatest as well.

Answer (score 0):

So after no way of fixing this, I upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04.2 LTS (3.2.0-24-virtual) and this just started working fine, without any intervention.